# C++ and C#: RSA Encryption / Decryption and sharing keys

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I just got my hands on Cryptography the first time. I have a few questions, espacially about sharing a public Key between two programs:

I have **two different applications**.
One is coded in C++ and running on a Linux Ubuntu Server. The other one is coded in C# and running on my local Windwos 7 Home-PC.

The two applications connect over TCP and I want to create a secure connection between them. I decided to use the **RSA-Algorithm**.
I created a Key-Pair on the Serverside and hard-coded them into the C++ application. The Public-Key of the server is also hardcoded into the C# application. Now, when the C# Application (Client) connects to the C++ application (Server), it should generate a personal Key-Pair and send the Public-Key to the server. From here on both sides can encrypt their data and send it to each other.

My problem is that I can't bring the Public-Keys to the "same layout". On the serverside I have to use the OpenSSL-Library since C++ does not come with a inbuilt RSA-Library. So the Key-Pair looks like this (example):

```
$ openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
$ openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA0DTV2eG8BrhPVWgrqR1PhI5BwLCsuAiBCCDmSShaOsh1uKFW
j7lgBGWyGT77X55DAgXwvjNg+odDfili71poeH/f5/1kCTTC6FFoV6inY0nAcOZ3
...
...
...
...
mxTUFS1Q+vPsmoPCN+C5bP+zv415usUg1Mx8sSly5IS0IQzp2kR8EekhqKLQb06p
2qZfVCuGEXzT+NoT10SOGtZ2+izb+EZM/yRkJFUQS2YwpwPmcZGbAUg=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0DTV2eG8BrhPVWgrqR1P
...
...
...
eH/f5/1kCTTC6FFoV6inY0nAcOZ3Ang1/fywxz5GVm430GuAqloZqNo/iwMZtHcU
aQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And when I create a Key-Pair in C#, it is in XML-Format:

```
    <RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>w0tU2IBTdZkLB3G9sze92KR67hM3qdbnYCujrp/GflJ/EMgP1dQxTuHOueq+3DzZnUZDVtYic2QDAdJDVDqRiIFbff7+l5IE24kcgIJSN6vJdnSVAVbSzfyZkftsd4faYx055ZYSH3N4Ev52QepgXVKz7G3S+n2xslzFs09SDOVKiUvmXQEG4CsRef4uB1Kk2ElrZBBpuU3G/V4gNpGkQ/TuPbizQL/Oao3HNhxnCsqxzOOCmNoPSiCesWSWpoPTJrBm2jfX5nDJi+l5u3dYrRLpT8h844Y2yplCeDe4M3/maee3d+0+7Ul7m7H73o9nI+cBLWPOy6IYxPMl/kaJxw==</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    <P>4NcTOPdRa05QZy7wKRO6wIYA+tKlc4KkrAMy//xkupYyuTpnt8Zt0B0nsltaOenpJSGMOJOb1VfCH+2R6ol8xNr3yyzz2izHGzNdQAk7V2ant3TIjdUiHS9h8ftTjiANPFO1XZlUyeXQiqe3Qzrjubv8J51Nmk7TssH2fheqrAE=</P>
    <Q>3lwFj3P8NLJVWRBEpPDJdjRRF4Qz7SNxthRdtvoifUtcMXw3UDnzsEDZ7A736vUUaaZArjAzO+x3arDaAJfQQk354ushwWw6MGoM0CudfCeUrxy9hi5afnxueWFbhJ+/k9nwPxn9EBBrqfYhNZbGW9vz6ZfHLUX95a5M2+9+1cc=</Q>
    <DP>vC0FV44WRJrczB8KvTZX/L2qoEIgWxaiP5zF2F0i6M7AUSpCmBqo2Z8tFCdE0meky4DSXJ+dsuaqABLTJto+5HrnHNLYnGcRlQBeMTQIyFOQVwiUubABxy9a6C2Sdsb4jN76UgX8YqXG7eUEim4FHfPpTDZpNpZ2s4uGg23HWAE=</DP>
    <DQ>eER/gWqzc/Es9oI1Dp1p6fQ8FCMeTtoH6/qyAYDjXK+BCwbriAoAQ0mgVOx3rW6nfsk8XLqXS4cHw/4pu35hVyuDx/dzh4G5K2yAx6t/f6KM6fX6kHPL4HP+8Mn2zRH2dcrABfFRjfnDseb9aVXGrfKWx7afNV6RCESxL5gnGws=</DQ>
    <InverseQ>wlndxTYxYmAo0+BcyJjVri6Iui/l5p+AGUi6xglmI8HHE3itgyCjfyfsKmsphH88uYYu/qdA80PTIKLdxo7HbUhOiT7f2vtBsCFzo7oB9kTDWrJ70xsQss4jkJGY8rJj4K7Dqwqa6s78ih1heeQhCJuevg8xiEUoqHOx5FtlQ4w=</InverseQ>
    <D>NlIczn+bN0mTdMWhY1ks2Daf7tqvj/EzuF9LDwZoGrjtmQhcxzhXYr6SVspBvla6nPFvR5cWTAxUfcwzaBlGY7a/cSNdQ2GdMkdIA0K8hbmltuokjBPPXPZW7PEHMZQ7HXiCoyaD8fWXP4lB8YG0viCD5U6C8aPGqnr9jquQgf9EwXxEZvdktOWLO5PJvd4XaQRk47UcNBkjWnwxO1vq28/OSWTNaoEQqpLNwimHEFHl3MN2IuME1zV4MvKyGsKsKO9EytLk/RD28UDFZGlxU6uNAEjOjQp++CgbFRCEHNOCas5kTa1/fuxVg8RdnFeowAq2otWwhwGlwGiJjjmoAQ==</D>
    </RSAKeyValue>
```

Finally, my questions:

- Is "----- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY -----" etc. actually a part of the Key? I'm pretty sure it's not, but I'm better making sure. The confusing thing is that when I leave this text in the key and encrypt/decrypt on the C++ application, it works (with OpenSSL lib).
- How can I bring the keys to the same structure so I can send them from one application to another and parse them correctly?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Why mess with your own created system and not use a existing proven system like a SSL connection between the client and the server?

Comment: Sure this is also a solution. But I want to get into the topic and understand how a asymetric encryption works between two clients.

Comment: Typicly clients don't use asymmetric to communicate. They use asymmetric encryption to transmit ephemeral session keys for symmetric encryption because it is orders of magnitude faster and is just as secure.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm now using SSL for my purpose :)